# Как получить данные отдельно по 4 символов, а не по 1 из цикла?

Tags: c++, строки, вывод

Как получить данные отдельно по 4 символов, а не по 1 из цикла?

Я бы хотел, чтобы переменная `i` выдавала 4 символа.

вот так `1239 2121 4511 7457 2562`

```
string test1 = "12392121451174572562";

int64_t test2 = 1239212145117457;
```

этот цикл явно не подходит для этого он выдает только по 1 символу.

```
for (char i : test1) {

    cout << i << " ";
}
```

Comment: Что такое "переменная `i`" в данном случае? У вас `char i`. Как в нее может поместиться 4 символа?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не этого хотите?...

```
int num = 0;
for (char i : test1) 
{
    cout << i;
    if (++num == 4)
    {
        cout << " ";
        num = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (size_t p4 = 4; p4 < test1.size(); p4 += 5) 
    test1.insert(p4, 1, ' ');
cout << test1;
```

Таким способом итерации цикла будет четыре раза меньше.
Но, если не хотите изменять исходную строку, то:

```
for (size_t p4 = 0; p4 < test1.size(); p4 += 4) 
    cout << test1.substr(p4, 4) << ' ';
```

Answer (score 1):

Лично я бы сделал так:

```
string test1 = "12392121451174572562";
string output = "";
for (int i = 0; i < test1.length(); i++) {
    if (i % 4 == 0 && i != 0)
        output += " ";
    output += test1[i];
}
cout << output;
```

Если есть предложения по коду, предлагайте правку, потому что кажется, что можна сделать лучше.

Comment: да, слышком много сравнений(на сравнения уходит львиная доля времени выполнения) и расчетов.